# When is an OpenCV imshow() window destroyed? (C++)

Tags: opencv

Can someone help me with the behavior of windows created with the imshow() function?  I'm replacing a call to the older cvNamedWindow(), which required a window to be explicitly destroyed and cleaned up when you're done with it.  imshow, on the other hand, seems to require no cleanup and to close the window after a user keypress.  Do I have any control over that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use namedWindow in Opencv 2.x

See this link: [namedWindow](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/highgui_user_interface.html?highlight=namedwindow#namedWindow)

To destroy an window, you can use `destroyWindow("windowname");`

Comment: `cv2.destroyWindow("windowname")` or `cv2.destroyAllWindows()`

Comment: or `cv::destroyAllWindows();` for OpenCV3